# Overriding Jmeter property in Run Taurus task Azure pipeline is not working

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, taurus

I am running jmeter from Taurus and I need a output kpi.jtl file with url listing.
I have tried passing parameter -o modules.jmeter.properties.save.saveservice.url='true' and
-o modules.jmeter.properties="{'jmeter.save.saveservice.url':'true'}". Pipeline is running successfully but the kpi.jtl doesn't have the url. Please help

I have tried few more options like editing jmeter.properties via pipeline - which broke the pipeline and expecting input from user
user.properities- Which is ineffective.

I am expecting kpi.jtl file with all the possible logs especially url.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using the wrong property, you should pass the next one:

```
modules.jmeter.csv-jtl-flags.url=true
```

More information: [CSV file content configuration](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#CSV-file-content-configuration)

However be informed that having a.jtl file "with all possible logs" is some form of a [performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) as it creates massive disk IO and may ruin your test. More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)